# Lambda without VPC has no internet access

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

My lambda function

- is not connected into a VPC ✅
- has the sufficient role's and permissions to access a particular S3 bucket ✅
- Runs in AWS China ✅
- Gets a valid session token for requesting into AWS Cloud regions ✅
- The lambda timeout is already maxed out with 900 seconds ✅

However, when running the handler, I get the following error message:

```
error=Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to context-stage-environment-my-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443 [context-stage-environment-my-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/1XX.5X.1X.2XX] failed: connect timed out
```

The section from the handler which causes the issue:

```
val s3ObjectInputStream: InputStream = sourceClient.getObject(GetObjectRequest(bucket.name, objKey)).objectContent

val bufferedS3Object: File = File.createTempFile(objKey, "")

Files.copy(s3ObjectInputStream, bufferedS3Object.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)

targetClient.putObject(PutObjectRequest(destinationBucket, objKey, bufferedS3Object))
```

Is there anything I could've missed?

Comment: Try increasing the default function timeout from 3 seconds to a larger value like 5 mins (max 15 mins)

Comment: Already set it to 900 seconds..

Comment: Just so that we understand what your code does ... the Lambda function runs in a China (Beijing?) region, downloads an object from S3 within region, then attempts to upload that object to an S3 bucket in Frankfurt? And it's the connection to the S3 service in Frankfurt that times out.

Comment: Almost correct. Its the other way around: It attempts to download the object from Frankfurt bucket and to upload the same object in Beijing bucket. The lambda gets notified about changes in the Frankfurt bucket via a SQS queue which also resides in Frankfurt region and works fine with this approach.

Comment: Does the security group attached to the lambda function allow egress on port 443?

Comment: Also check that the bucket is in the same region as the lambda function, if not, make sure you specify the bucket region when creating the s3 client

Answer (score 0):

Your bucket is probably configured to accept only SSL requests, thus when you make the HTTP call it tries to hit it on port 443 which is default for HTTPS, either modify bucket policy to accept non SSL connections which in this case you risk of getting all your data stolen during transit or use HTTPS to make the request.